# $.inArray() : check if array value has "+" inside

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I have an array like below created by jQuery:

```
var arr = ["a+ab","g+cc","bc","dk"]
```

I'd like to do a checker in order to loop through the whole array and return only the array value with `+`.

After handling, the result should be:

```
var arr2 = ["a+ab","g+cc"]
```

Should I do it by using `$.inArray()`?

If I want to get the value with + sign I do:

```
var arr = ["a+ab", "g+cc", "bc", "dk"];

var res = arr.filter(function(v) {
  return v.indexOf('+') > -1;
})

console.log(res);
```

What if I want the the value without + sign?

```
var arr = ["a+ab", "g+cc", "bc", "dk"];

var res = arr.filter(function(v) {
  return v.indexOf('+') > 1;
})

console.log(res);
```

Is the above correct?

Update:

```
function keywordArray() {
    var keywordArrayRow = [];

    $(".tag-container .tag-item .word").each(function (i, e) {
        keywordArrayRow.push($(e).text());
    });

    var keywordArray = keywordArrayRow.filter(function(v) {
        return v.indexOf('+') == -1;
    })
    return keywordArrayRow;
}
function AndkeywordArray() {
    var AndkeywordArrayRow = [];

    $(".tag-container .tag-item .word").each(function (i, e) {
        AndkeywordArrayRow.push($(e).text());
    });

    var AndkeywordArray = AndkeywordArrayRow.filter(function(v) {
        return v.indexOf(' + ') > -1;
    })

    return AndkeywordArray;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think **[`$.inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)** can be use here. **[`$.inArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)** is used to search for a specified value within an array and return its index (or -1 if not found).

---

For filtering an array  use native JavaScript **[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method

```js
var arr = ["a+ab", "g+cc", "bc", "dk"];

var res = arr.filter(function(v) {
  return v.indexOf('+') > -1;
})

console.log(res);
```

---

**UPDATE 1 :**

In case if you want element which are not contains `+` symbol then use following code.

```js
var arr = ["a+ab", "g+cc", "bc", "dk"];

var res = arr.filter(function(v) {
  return v.indexOf('+') == -1;
})

console.log(res);
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

Inside `keywordArray` function returning the original array instead of filtered array.

```
function keywordArray() {
  var keywordArrayRow = [];

  $(".tag-container .tag-item .word").each(function(i, e) {
    keywordArrayRow.push($(e).text());
  });

  var keywordArray = keywordArrayRow.filter(function(v) {
    return v.indexOf('+') == -1;
  })
  return keywordArray;
  //---------^------ change here
}
```

Comment: what if i want the other way around? only value without +

Comment: should i do  return v.indexOf('+') > 1;?

Comment: @anson920520 : if index position need to be greater then 1 then use it

Comment: @anson920520 : updated , `indexOf()` returns `-1` if not found element

Comment: the one you updated seem not working it gets everything contain in my array

Comment: @anson920520 : no way , `return v.indexOf('+') == -1;`

Comment: there's juz a small bug i fixed it , thanks in advnace